# It's possible make with map same loop for?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, for-loop

It's Possible to make with '.map()' same:

```
var array = new Array();    
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
array[i]=i
}
```

Comment: Try it, before asking.

Comment: if i asked maybe i have try it....

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read community guidelines towards posting meaningful questions showing reasonable effort and research. Please provide more data like code samples and output and the subsequent errors. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do to something like that with Array#map, you need to create an empty array, and [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it with items, and then map them to the wanted values:

```js
const array = new Array(10).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);

console.log(array);
```

A better way is to use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and give it an object with length:

```js
const array = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i);

console.log(array);
```